# Basic Database design question

Tags: database, database-design

I'm designing the database for a WCF service I'm building and have a question about how I should design it:
I have a `Subscriptions` table, an `Events` table, and a `lu_Type` table.

```
**Subscription**                  **lu_EventType**
SubscriptionId int  ID PK         TypeId      int ID PK
CustomerId     int  FK            Description nvarchar
TypeId         int? FK  
Description    nvarchar

**Event**  
EventId        int  ID PK  
CustomerId     int  FK
SubscriptionId int  FK  
EventTime      datetime
TypeId         int?
Description    nvarchar
```

A `Customer` can have multiple `Subscription`'s.
The `TypeId` is nullable because there are two types of Subscriptions that a Customer can be subscribed to. Known events, which will be from the `lu_Type` table, and unknown events, where the `Subscription` has a null TypeId and only a Description.
Once an `Event` is logged, it will be displayed in a website based on `Customer`.

1. For known events, when the `Event` will have a TypeId, should I include the `Description` of the `Event` in the record? Or should I just leave the `Description` blank? It would take up more space in the db if I included it, but it would make retrieval/display much easier. I don't know enough about the inner workings to know if either of those is a non-issue or not. Or is there perhaps a better path altogether? (I can only have one `Event` table though, it needs to be generic.) Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following are true:

- The description of an event is directly related to the type
- All events of the same type should have the same description
- Changes to the event type's description should be reflected on existing events

You should *not* include `Description` on the event, but instead join to the event type table to obtain it.

Otherwise, the description should be included on the event record, since it is not directly related to the event type.

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. And you made me realize I don't need the TypeId or Description on the Event because I have the SubscriptionId, and can just JOIN on that. - - - So in general db design, it's always better to do a JOIN than to have duplicate columns, correct?

Comment: @G_M: **Absolutely**. You never want to duplicate data in the database if it can be avoided, and it can be avoided in almost all (if not all) cases. This is part of what makes a relational database "relational"; you use the relationships between entities in order to retrieve data, rather than duplicating the data.

Answer (score 1):

- **Customer** can **subscribe** to many **events**.
- One **event** can be delivered to many **customers**.
- **Event** can be **known** or **unknown**. A known event **is an Event** (sub-type).
- Known events have all columns as unknown events and few more specific columns.

[image]